# What if the internet was founded only for the rich and high class people?

Tags: society

What if the internet were only for the rich and high class people? would we still live in an anarchy? Would the rich be much smarter and developed than the poor people? How would our society look? Would our establishments look different?
how will it effect the middle class? etc...

Comment: It is not an answer, just hint. It wouldn't. Or rather, it was only for scientists who made it, rich companies and rich individuals, at the beginning. Because it was expensive to operate and access. But no one wanted to *keep* it that way. Any would they, in your story? Why, given the opportunities to earn even more when it's popular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All disruption caused by the internet wouldn't happen. Newspapers wouldn't be closing. Uber wouldn't exist. Ditto Google, Amazon Books, online dating, online buying and selling. They never would happen.

Most of the populace would get their information the old-fashioned way pre-internet. The disruption caused by the internet wouldn't be there to change them.

The rich, and this will come as a sad shock to them, are only a small but well-heeled niche market. They're not big enough to change the world the internet in the last two decades has.

Wind the clock back two decades and look at what was happening then, and with an internet for the rich only, we would still be doing it today in 2016. Isn't that shocking?

Answer (score 1):

The internet is only as useful as the people posting to it. If only the rich can access it, then they're going to be the only people posting. So the question then becomes, what sort of things would they post? And are there enough rich people to make building the net worthwhile in the first place?

For the rest of the world, things carry on in a pre-internet way.

But the technology usually gets cheaper and more widespread, so even if the rich get the first bite at the tech, it's not going to be long before it gets more affordable.